# USB 3.0 USRP b210 stops working and lsusb freezes

Tags: 14.04, usb, lts

I am using ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to run an opensource radio software that requires this specific version (as well as low-latency kernel 3.19). 
Right after i boot the PC and execute the commands uhd_find_devices and lsusb, both commands work fine and show the usrp connected.
The problem is that when i run the software and require USB 3.0 usage to connect to the USRP, it freezes and lsusb hangs forever and can't be killed by Ctrl+C.

I've seen many similar questions online, but that i've seen none of them provided a useful answer, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

The lsusb process cannot be killed, because it is in an uninterruptible sleep, probably waiting for a syscall that never returns, due to a kernel module (driver) bug. There is a good explanation of this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197475/230540) which gives a full answer (I can't take credit for it!)